# A relation between the law of multiplication with rate of travel and time.

Tags: physics, kinematics

I am reading the book [Algebra for the practical man](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Algebra_for_the_practical_man.html?id=wu3uAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), chapter 1, article 6.

Uptil article-6 the author has explained the operations of addition on positive and negative numbers. Now in article-6 he is explaining(not defining) the multiplication using the concept of negative time.

> - In the 4th point the author presumes that the multiplication of *rate* with [time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_physics) will give the distance moved.

In the light of this concept he concludes that $−ve×−ve=+ve $. 
 The author states in the beginning of article-6:

> We shall consider motion to the right of the starting point as positive ($+$) and motion to the left of the starting point as negative ($-$).

Then in the  4th point he says:

> If the train is now at the starting point and has been traveling to the left, where was it 5 hours ago?
>   Motion to the left $\times$ Past time
>   $(- 40)      \times  (-5) = +200 $

Here ($-40$) is the *rate* at which the train moves and ($-5$) is *time* elapsed.

My question is:

> - As the time changes from $0$ to $-5$ the train moves from the starting point towards right in the past, shouldn't we assume the *rate* of train positive and conclude$(+40)      \times  (-5) = +200 $?.
> - If my interpretation is correct then does it mean that the author's assumption that
>         *rate* $\times$ time = *distance* is incorrect?

**NOTE:** Since division has not been defined uptil article 6 we cannot use the definition of division.

Comment: It's not moving backwards in space, it's moving backwards in time. That's why the time of $5$ is inverted to $-5$ and the velocity stays the same. If you invert the velocity as well, you should expect the answer to be the same as moving with the original velocity forward in time. The acceptance of the author's assumption that *Velocity x time = distance* is being taken as a given to prove multiplication, so the logic must follow this rule. Which means given the premise that this rule is correct, here's how multiplication works. If you don't accept that rule, the explanation has no basis.

Comment: @RandomUser If it moves backward in time then it will also move backward in space, won't it? Like when a video is played backward the positions of things are  changed to their past positions.

Comment: Exactly. The position of them changes, and they appear to be moving backwards, but that's because time is. If you took a video of a car moving forward and rewound it, you wouldn't see the driver throw the gear into reverse. Another way to think of it is to draw a graph of position over time. When looking back in time, you're just moving left on the graph. The change of position over time (the slope of the line, which is the velocity) doesn't change when you do this.

Comment: @RandomUser Here is the point. The velocity is defined for the positive time,that is $v=\dfrac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}$, $t_2-t_1$ is the magnitude of future time. The slope is defined from this. The problem at hand is that uptil art-6 author hasn't defined division. The author simply states:"_We shall consider motion to the right of the starting point as positive (+) and motion to the left of the starting point as negative (-)._". Now if we move from present to past the velocity then should be +ve acc. to author's statement.

Comment: Then you can have $v(t_2-t_1)=x_2-x_1$ if you're not allowed to divide. This even follows. $vt=x$, so $x_2-x_1=vt_2-vt_1$.

Comment: @RandomUser If we are not allowed to divide then we can't use the definition $v=\dfrac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}$. We have to use author's definition. Btw... I know that if we use the satandard definition the logic is correct$\ -\ v(t_2-t_1)=(x_2-x_1)\implies v(t_1-t_2)=(x_1-x_2)$, now substituting the values $(-40)(0-5)=(+200)$ but the problem is can we use the relation $s_1-s_2=r_1-r_2 \implies s_2-s_1=r_1-r_2$? We are yet defining operations on negative numbers.

Comment: Please consider adding comment before downvoting.

Comment: Before voting please consider this discussion: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13745/103816

Comment: All the down-votes this question make no sense.  My suspicion is that people who don't know how to answer a question but think they should know, express themselves in that way.

Answer (score 1):

The rate is negative because the train is moving toward the left.

The time is negative because it's five hours before the time we're calling zero.

Negative rate times negative time equals positive distance, and positive means it's to the right of the location we're calling zero.

You say as time changes from $0$ to $-5$, the train moves rightward.  Rightward does indeed correspond to **positive** distance.  The change in time is $-5$ and the change in distance is $+200$ therefore the rate is
$$
\text{rate} = \frac{\text{change in distance}}{\text{change in time}} = \frac{+200}{-5} = -40.
$$
The rate is negative.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but I guess you have missed the last line of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the downvotes to this question either.

The author defines $\mbox{distance}= \mbox{rate} \times \mbox{time}$. Somewhere in his definition of rate, he states that rate is positive if moving right, negative if moving left. Perhaps what wasn't clear is that this definition also assumes that the arrow of time has been fixed: that time is increasing. Therefore, rate is actually *independent* of (the sign of) time. In other words, when speaking of a rate, the convention should be "with respect to increasing time." You probably know from other places that velocity is distance/time, where time is *increasing* (positive). The reason for all this is to establish a convention so that when talking about a car moving at 50mph, we both assume that this is defined with respect to increasing time (otherwise we always have to establish a convention, which is very annoying).  Notice that the author does not need the notion of division in any of this. Again, to be precise in his defition, the author needs to mention that the rate (velocity) is with-respect-to increasing time.

Given that definition, the problem should be clear. If we reverse time, then the distance covered correctly reverses as well, so if $d=vt$, then $-d=v(-t)$.

To clarify even further, some time ago mathematicians establish that $5$ is "positive five" and $-5$ is "negative five." This is a set convention, so it's unlikely that you would think $5$ is negative. In the same way, the concept of rate is fixed with respect to increasing time. The author extends the definition of distance covered to negative time by multiplying by negative time instead, in the same way that you multiply $5$ by $(-1)$ to get $-5$.